# Why is transaction hash bitcoin millions worth txid

Tags: hash, blockchain, bitcoin

i made a bitcoin transaction and it generateed a hash (txid)

6572dc66810b4710a0db5e00cd46704f80be7fee1b0603ad15724e63ded994f7

when search for it

https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/6572dc66810b4710a0db5e00cd46704f80be7fee1b0603ad15724e63ded994f7

it shows like 10 different addresses with values between 0 and 32.31404275 BTC

why is that? because of the platform i use that send like pakages of transactions or why?

It says

> This transaction was first broadcast to the Bitcoin network on October
> 04, 2021 at 12:07 PM GMT+2.  The transaction currently has 183
> confirmations on the network.  At the time of this transaction,
> 33.11857777 BTC was sent with a value of $1,579,691.42. The current value of this transaction is now $1,654,672.04.  Learn more about how
> transactions work.

Can anyone explain please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Bitcoin transactions are essentially a collection of inputs and outputs.

A transaction takes in an input and can divide that input into as many outputs as required. Once an input is used, it can no longer be used again and the newly created outputs can be used as inputs for other transactions. Importantly, a transaction must consume the entire value of an input so if any "change" is left, that change is just another output likely pointing to another address in the custody of the input's owner.

The input in the transaction you have linked has a value of 33.11859643 BTC and is dividing that value into 10 different outputs. The largest output is likely "change" from the input. By bundling many outputs into the same transaction, the entity that made the transaction is saving transaction fees.